# Узнать позицию в сортировке ORDER BY в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица, где подсчитаваются статистики игроков. Сейчас вывожу топ игроков всем

`SELECT user, event_stat FROM stats ORDER BY event_stat DESC LIMIT 9;'`

Но хочу последней строчкой выводить игроку ЕГО место в статистике.
Для этого мне нужно узнать на каком месте был бы игрок если бы я запросил сразу все строки `ORDER BY event_stat DESC`

Есть возможность узнать номер строки конкретного юзера запросом? Не хочу делать так:
`SELECT count(*) FROM stats where event_stat > $usersEventStat;` т.к. у игроков может быть одинаковый показатель 'event_stat' (тогда место будет зависеть от id строки в базе) и место в топе будет указано не точно.

Comment: ```SELECT count(*) FROM stats where event_stat > $usersEventStat;``` вот в таком варианте место будет зависить не от id, для всех у кого совпал опыт - будет одно место... т.е. условно на месте 200 - может быть 10 человек...

Comment: Есть два варианта: взять на PHP обработать и просто поставить элемент в конец, а можно вести rownumber в запросе и нужной строке сделать максимальный номер выборки + 1. И сортировку по этому полю

Comment: Используйте Union и запрос с поиском по id игрока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы получить номер строки конкретного пользователя в результатах запроса, можно использовать выражение ROW_NUMBER() в качестве параметра функции SELECT.

Например, для получения полной таблицы статистики, отсортированной по убыванию показателя event_stat, и добавления столбца с номером строки для каждого пользователя, можно использовать следующий запрос:

```
SELECT
  user,
  event_stat,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_stat DESC) as row_number
FROM stats
```

Этот запрос вернет таблицу со столбцами user, event_stat и row_number, где row_number будет хранить номер строки для каждого пользователя. Например, если пользователь с наибольшим значением event_stat находится в первой строке таблицы, то его значение row_number будет равно 1.